# Coulombs's Law (Electrostatics )

Tags: electrostatics, momentum, conservation-laws, coulombs-law

Why will two different size charges exert the same attractive or repulsive force on one another? Surely the bigger charge exerts a greater force on the smaller charge and vice versa?

Comment: Are you talking about different charges (e.g. 1 Coulomb and 0.2 Coulomb) or about two charges with different sizes (e.g. 1 Coulomb on a sphere with radius 0.5m and 1 Coulomb on a sphere with radius 0.25m)?

Comment: [Newton's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_third_law)

Comment: @PMPJohn yes charges

Comment: Well, as John Rennie already said, it doesn't matter how big or charged the charges are, the two forces $F_{1 \to 2}$ and $F_{2 \to 1}$ are the same, it's just the **effect** that may be different. For example, a massive sphere (say, 1 ton) has a charge of 1 Coulomb. Of course a small sphere with only 1kg and a charge of 1 Coulomb will be accelerated away from the massive sphere rapidly due to Coulomb force, but the massive sphere also feels the same force. It's just that it's not accelerating much due to its inertia.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is Newton's third law. Third law: *When one body exerts a force on a second body, the second body simultaneously exerts a force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction on the first body.* See [Newton's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)

Answer (score 0):

> Surely the bigger charge exerts a greater force on the smaller charge
>   and vice versa?

For concreteness, stipulate that the two charged particles have charge $q_1$ and $q_2$ and that $q_1 \gt q_2$.

It's true that the electric field of the first (second) charge is stronger (weaker) at the location of the second (first) charge *but* it's also true that the second (first) charge has less (more) charge to 'couple' to this field.

Since the force is the product of the charge and electric field, the stronger electric field times the smaller charge equals the weaker electric field times the larger charge.